# Change color of cell if sum of row drops below 2

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I'm working on a sheet to help me keep track of inventory at a bookstore. Here is a watered down [version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_yt_vVc5199hZY5BLzRa2Q6oep6LtOZJUZ9qyojxo0k/edit#gid=0). There are 19 titles in total, kept at three different warehouses. I'm working on a notification system where the top box will turn red if the sum of books in any single title drop to 3, so I know it time to restock.

How can I do that?

NOTE: I can't add another column to get the sum value. The original spreadsheet is pretty crowded as it is.

The full sheet is in the copy of [Inventories](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_yt_vVc5199hZY5BLzRa2Q6oep6LtOZJUZ9qyojxo0k/edit#gid=248042451).

Answer (score 0):

A custom formula in conditional formatting to achieve this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(C3:E3),ROW(C3:C21)),ROW(C3:C21),C3:E21))<3)`

Comment: Wil it work if the columns aren't next to one another?